# CoreData relationship , with Delete

Tags: ios, core-data

If I delete a CoreData record from an entity, does that also delete the relationship that record had with another record in another entity?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It depends on the *Delete Rule* that you have enabled for the relationship. The [Core Data Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdRelationships.html) documents these (extracted below). Have a look in the inspector to see which option you have set for your relationships. If you have a specific data model which you want comment on you should edit your question to be more specific.

> Deny
>
> If there is at least one object at the relationship destination, then the source object cannot be deleted. For example, if you want to remove a department, you must ensure that all the employees in that department are first transferred elsewhere (or fired!) otherwise the department cannot be deleted.
>
> Nullify
>
> Set the inverse relationship for objects at the destination to null. For example, if you delete a department, set the department for all the current members to null. This only makes sense if the department relationship for an employee is optional, or if you ensure that you set a new department for each of the employees before the next save operation.
>
> Cascade
>
> Delete the objects at the destination of the relationship.
>   For example, if you delete a department, fire all the employees in that department at the same time.
>
> No Action
>
> Do nothing to the object at the destination of the relationship. For example, if you delete a department, leave all the employees as they are, even if they still believe they belong to that department.

Comment: And be sure to always use inverse relations. We generated a datamodel in code which did not have these and ended up with problems even if we were using nullify.

Comment: Great point - it's easy to create an inverse relationship in the Data Model Editor when it's presented there for you, but could be very easily forgotten if you're working directly in code.